# Reading fileModificationDate

Tags: objective-c

How do I access the fileModificationDate

```
    NSString *docsDir = [NSHomeDirectory() stringByAppendingPathComponent:
                         @"TempiPad"];
    NSFileManager *localFileManager=[[NSFileManager alloc] init];
    NSDirectoryEnumerator *dirEnum =
    [localFileManager enumeratorAtPath:docsDir];
    NSString *file;

    // List all files in docsDir
    while (file = [dirEnum nextObject]) {
        NSLog(@"File = %@",file);
        NSError *attributesError = nil;
        NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:file error:&attributesError];

        NSString *fileModificationDate = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
        NSLog(@"ModDate = %@",fileModificationDate);

        } 
    }
```

This just outputs (null). Eventually I will want to compare the fileModificationDate for two files, so how will I do that?

Answer (score 2):

IIRC, you need to append the filename to the directory path; something like:

```
while (file = [dirEnum nextObject]) {
    NSLog(@"File = %@",file);
    NSError *attributesError = nil;
    file = [docsDir stringByAppendingPathComponent:file];
    NSDictionary *fileAttributes = [[NSFileManager defaultManager] attributesOfItemAtPath:file error:&attributesError];

    NSDate *fileModificationDate = [fileAttributes objectForKey:NSFileModificationDate];
    NSLog(@"ModDate = %@",fileModificationDate);

    } 
}
```

And, as more tension said, `NSFileModificationDate` is an `NSDate`, not an `NSString`.

Answer (score 0):

`NSFileModificationDate` returns an `NSDate` instance, not an `NSString`. See:

[NSFileModificationDate](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/#documentation/Cocoa/Reference/Foundation/Classes/NSDictionary_Class/Reference/Reference.html#//apple_ref/occ/instm/NSDictionary/fileModificationDate)